# Tableview ChangeListener - NPE

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho duas TableView (`tabela1` e `tabela2`) uma ao lado da outra.

O que preciso fazer é: ao selecionar um item na `tabela1` seja selecionado o item correspondente na `tabela2`.

Até aqui tudo bem, foi fácil, mas preciso reproduzir o mesmo efeito na `tabela2`, e é quando surge o `NPE`, o *listener* aplicado na `tabela1` entra em conflito com o listener da `tabela2`.

Tentei criar um evento no `focusedProperty()`, mas sem sucesso.

Fiz uma aplicação de teste para poder postar aqui, mas como não caberia todo código, segue
link para download: [TableView - Teste](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__KOU0JoCQGNEU0VllBSFNKODQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: tente criar um [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o problema e poste-o aqui, pois ficará mais fácil de te ajudar. Só com o seu listener vai ser difícil.

Comment: Opa, adicionei dois links do video da minha aplicação funcionando, dê uma olhada

Comment: acho que ainda não entendeu o que é o [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Você precisa de reduzir o seu problema para algo mínimo e compilável, é um ótimo exercício de debug e ajuda-nos a responder sua pergunta. Postar vídeos não irá ajudar muito, poste um **código completo** que *reproduza o erro que está enfrentando.*

Comment: Entao amigo muito obrigado pelo seu esforço em tentar mim ajudar, mas os códigos são aqueles já citados como My Listener, mas assim que eu chegar em casa vou explicar passo a passo o código muito obrigado

Comment: novamente os código que postou lá estão muito longe de serem **compiláveis** e **verificáveis** só postou os listeners e quer verificar algo que ocorre na Interface gráfica.

Comment: Boa noite, reformulei a pergunta, fiz uma aplicação de teste, mas como não caberia todo código deixei o link para download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução dada pelo [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266520/tableview-changelistener-conflict/25267670#25267670)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoTableTest extends Application {

private ChangeListener<Number> table1SelectionListener ;
private ChangeListener<Number> table2SelectionListener ;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Person> table1 = createTableView() ;
    TableView<Person> table2 = createTableView() ;

    table1.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    table2.getSelectionModel().select(0);

    table1SelectionListener = (obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
        int table1SelectedIndex = table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
        int table2SelectedIndex = table2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
        if (table1SelectedIndex != table2SelectedIndex) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> table2.getSelectionModel().select(table1SelectedIndex));
        }
    };

    table2SelectionListener = (obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
        int table1SelectedIndex = table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
        int table2SelectedIndex = table2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
        if (table1SelectedIndex != table2SelectedIndex) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> table1.getSelectionModel().select(table2SelectedIndex));
        }
    };
    table1.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(table1SelectionListener);
    table2.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(table2SelectionListener);

    HBox root = new HBox(5, table1, table2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private TableView<Person> createTableView() {
    TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());

    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().lastNameProperty());

    TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().emailProperty());

    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

    table.getItems().addAll(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")        
    );

    return table ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public static class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty email ;


    Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName",
                firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email", email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get();
    }

}
```

}